# Example on how to config google cloud storage with KnpGaufetteBundle

Tags: symfony, google-cloud-storage, gaufrette

I am trying to configure a [KnpGaufretteBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) to use `Google Cloud Storage` for storing my files. This is the config:

```
## definition of the GCS service
app.google_cloud_storage.service:
    class: \Google_Service_Storage
    factory_class: Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\DependencyInjection\Factory\GoogleCloudStorageAdapterFactory
    factory_method: 'create'
    arguments: 
        - "123@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
        - "http://localhost/file.p12"
        - "pwd"

## config of knp_gaufrette
knp_gaufrette:
    stream_wrapper: ~
    adapters:
        gcs_minn_images:
            google_cloud_storage:
                service_id: 'app.google_cloud_storage.service'
                bucket_name: 'minn-images'
    filesystems:
        gcs_minn_images_fs:
            adapter: gcs_minn_images
```

The error message I got is:

**ContextErrorException in GoogleCloudStorageAdapterFactory.php line 16:
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\DependencyInjection\Factory\GoogleCloudStorageAdapterFactory::create() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder, string given, called in /home/amine/NetBeansProjects/tuto/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 724 and defined**

According to the error message, I gave a string of stead of ContainerBuilder. Great! Let's add the ContainerBuilder to the arguments as follows:

```
## definition of the GCS service
app.google_cloud_storage.service:
    class: \Google_Service_Storage
    factory_class: Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\DependencyInjection\Factory\GoogleCloudStorageAdapterFactory
    factory_method: 'create'
    arguments: 
        - @service_container
        - "123@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
        - "http://localhost/file.p12"
        - "pwd"
```

The result is again an error:

**Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\DependencyInjection\Factory\GoogleCloudStorageAdapterFactory::create() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder, instance of appDevDebugProjectContainer given, called in /home/amine/NetBeansProjects/tuto/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 724 and defined**

So now, the error is telling me that I provide an instance of appDevDebugProjectContainer in stead of ContainerBuilder!!

Ok, let's have a look to `/home/amine/NetBeansProjects/tuto/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php` on line 724...

```
class appDevDebugProjectContainer extends Container{
// ...
/**
 * Gets the 'app.google_cloud_storage.service' service.
 *
 * This service is shared.
 * This method always returns the same instance of the service.
 *
 * @return \Google_Service_Storage A Google_Service_Storage instance.
 */
protected function getApp_GoogleCloudStorage_ServiceService()
{
    return $this->services['app.google_cloud_storage.service'] =\Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\DependencyInjection\Factory\GoogleCloudStorageAdapterFactory::create($this, '123@developer.gserviceaccount.com', 'http://localhost/file.p12', 'pwd');
}
```

I am really lost...
So, is there any **complete example** to config google cloud storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution. You have to create your own factory class as described in the documentation of the bundle:

### Factory class

```
<?php

namespace Minn\AdsBundle\Factory;
/**
 * Description of GoogleCloudStorageServiceFactory
 */
class GoogleCloudStorageServiceFactory {

    public function createService() {
        // creating the google client
        $client = new \Google_Client();

        // setting the service acount credentials
        $serviceAccountName = '123@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
        $scopes = array(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',
        );
        $privateKey = file_get_contents('http://localhost/f.p12');
        $privateKeyPassword = 'pwd';

        $credential = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
                $serviceAccountName, $scopes, $privateKey, $privateKeyPassword);

        // set assertion credentials
        $client->setAssertionCredentials($credential);

        // creating and returning the service
        return new \Google_Service_Storage($client);
    }

}
```

### The config.yml file

```
app.google_cloud_storage.service:
    class: \Google_Service_Storage
    factory: [Minn\AdsBundle\Factory\GoogleCloudStorageServiceFactory, createService]


knp_gaufrette:
    stream_wrapper: ~
    adapters:
        gcs_images:
            google_cloud_storage:
                service_id: 'app.google_cloud_storage.service'
                bucket_name: 'images'
filesystems:
    gcs_images_fs:
        adapter: gcs_images

vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    storage: gaufrette   
    mappings:
        motors_files:
            upload_destination: gcs_images_fs
            namer: vich_uploader.namer_origname
            delete_on_remove: true
```

That's was it...

Hope it will help others...